# Laravelのrouteエラー: Route [tasks.show] not defined. がなぜ解消されたかわからない

Tags: laravel

Laravelのrouteで確認したいことがあります。
下記エラーは解消されましたがなぜ解消されたかわかりません。

```
Route [tasks.show] not defined. tasklist/resources/views/tasks/index.blade.php
```

tasks.showをusers.showに変更したら解消されます。
tasks.showとはtasksフォルダの中のshow.blade.phpだと思ってました。
私の環境にusersフォルダは存在してません。

このtasks.showのtasksとは何でしょうか？

web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'TasksController@index');

// create: 新規作成用のフォームページ
Route::get('tasks/create', 'TasksController@create')->name('tasks.create');

// ユーザ登録
Route::get('signup', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('signup.get');
Route::post('signup', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('signup.post');

// ログイン認証
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login.post');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout.get');

// ユーザ機能
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController', ['only' => ['store', 'destroy']]);
```

TasksController.php

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $task = Task::find($id);

        return view('tasks.show', [
            'task' => $task,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ルーターで設定されているルートの名前です。

ルート設定ファイル(routes/web.phpなど)を確認してみてください。`->name('users.show')`のように定義されているルートはないでしょうか。

---

ルーターファイルの追記を受けて回答も追記します。

この場合、

> ```
>     Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
> ```

で ルート"`users.index`"と"`users.show`"が登録されています。

> tasks.showをusers.showに変更したら解消されます。

はこのためです。(おそらくエラーが消えるだけで理想の挙動になっているわけではないのではないでしょうか)

`Route::resource`はCRUDを実現するルートを自動登録しますが、すべてが必要ではないことも多いので、`only`でホワイトリスト化できます。ここではindexとshowですね。

[LaravelでRoute::resourceを使うときに気をつけること - Qiita](https://qiita.com/sympe/items/9297f41d5f7a9d91aa11)
[コントローラ 6.x Laravel](https://readouble.com/laravel/6.x/ja/controllers.html?header=%25E3%2583%25AA%25E3%2582%25BD%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2582%25B9%25E3%2582%25B3%25E3%2583%25B3%25E3%2583%2588%25E3%2583%25AD%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%25A9%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2581%25B8%25E3%2581%25AE%25E3%2583%25AB%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%2588%25E8%25BF%25BD%25E5%258A%25A0)

一方でtasksに関するルートは

> ```
>    Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController', ['only' => ['store', 'destroy']]);
> ```

で登録されています。(createだけわかれちゃってますがとりあえず無視します)
usersと同様に、`tasks.store`と`tasks.destroy`のみが登録されているようです。当然ながら`show`は入ってないので、`tasks.show`というルートは登録されていません。

つまりは、ここに`show`を追加すれば、本来の解決が可能でしょう。

Comment: ルートではtasks.showやusers.showも設定されてません。よくわかりません。

Comment: 少し質問を誤読していた部分があったようですが、とりあえず追記したので確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。とりあえずcreateも一緒にしました。routeの理解が深まりました。また別の事で質問するかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。